# npm install -g gatsby-cli is not working when im trying to install gatsby-cli

Tags: npm, gatsby, npm-install, gatsby-plugin

Im trying to install gatsby-cli for the first time using "npm install -g gatsby-cli" but Im getiing so many npm errors , i have gone through many solutions which are posted on internet but nothing seems to work for me ,  im stuck on this for days now. your help would be really appreciated.

**these are the errors im getting...**
[image: these are the errors im getting...]

Comment: Can you detail what "solutions posted on internet" have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

Try this command:

```
sudo npm install -g gatsby-cli
```

Comment: i get this message " /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory" after running above command

Comment: Don't install dependencies with `sudo`...

Comment: make sure you could installed node, after that run node version command: node -v
if you'll getting some error so please install node first.